# Ruby rails - jquery ajax submit form

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Is this correct to send an ajax request?
This code isn't working, what do I need to change here? Any better way to send an ajax form?

```
<%=  form_tag item_create_path, :remote => true, :id => 'create_item'  do %>
  <p>
   <b> <%= label_tag :"Name" %></b> <%= text_field_tag :name, nil, :maxlength => 40, :size => 70 %>
   <b> <%= label_tag :"Date" %></b> <%= text_field_tag :date, nil, :maxlength => 10, :size => 10, :value => Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>
   <b> <%= label_tag :"Time" %></b> <%= text_field_tag :time, nil, :maxlength => 10, :size => 10, :value => Time.now.localtime.strftime("%H:%M:%S") %>
   </p>
  <p>
   <b> <%= label_tag :Description %></b> <%= text_field_tag :description, nil, :maxlength => 50, :size => 50 %>
  </p>

<%= hidden_field_tag :type, nil, :value => "new" %>
<p class="button"><%= submit_tag "  Create  ",:onclick=>"javascript:submitForm()" %></p>
<% end %>


function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: '/item/create', data:$('#create_item').serialize(), success: function(response) {
        $('#create_item').find('#item').html(response);
    }});

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this it will sure work

```
    <%= form_for(:customer, :url => {:controller => "subscribers", :action => "change_password"}, :html => {:id => 'edit_password_form', :method => :get, :onsubmit => "return false;"}) do |f| %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "ids", :id => "ids"%>
      <div class="ports-fields">
        <div class="pass">
          <label style="margin-top:4px;">Password</label> 
          <%= f.password_field :password, :class=> 'fields', :placeholder => 'Password' %>
        </div>
        <div class="pass">
           <label>Confirm Password</label> 
           <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class=> 'fields', :placeholder => 'Password Confirmation' %>
        </div>
        <div class="change-pass-btn-submit"> 
           <%= submit_tag "CHANGE PASSWORD", :id => "edit_password_btn" %>
        </div>
        <!--modify ports ends-->
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

and jquery code for this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $("#edit_port_btn").click(function() {
            var container = $("#info");
            $("#edit_port_form").submit(function() {
                $(this).unbind('submit').ajaxSubmit({
                    success: function(data) {
                        container.html(data);
                        hudMsg('success', 'Modify ports successfully.');
                    }
                })
            }); 
       });
   </script>
```

And enjoyy....