# Post link using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211032/ruby-rails-jquery-ajax-submit-form) as reference, i'm trying to post links using ajax (which i'm totally new to so please bear with me). At this point, nothing happens when i click the 'post' button.

My form looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for [question, Link.new], :remote => true, :id => 'create_item' do |f| %>
<%= f.input :body %>
<%= f.button :submit, "Post", :onclick=>"javascript:submitForm()", class: "button" %>
```

and the jquery looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST', 
        url: 'questions/:question_id/links/new',
        data:$('#create_item').serialize(), 
        success: function(response) {
            $('#create_item').find('#item').html(response);
        }
    });

    return false;
}

</script>
```

Comment: even though your onclick handler(`submitForm`) is returning false, the event handler `onclick=>"javascript:submitForm()"` is not returning that value to the event caller... so I assume the forms default submit is not prevented which might be blocking the ajax request form being submitted... so try `onclick=>" return submitForm()"`

Comment: @Barmar suggested the same thing but it does't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
:onclick => "return submitForm()"
```

The click handler needs to return `false` to prevent the default submission. Your `submitForm` function returns false, but you weren't returning that from the handler.

Also, you don't need `javascript:` in `onXXX` attributes. That's only needed in attributes that contain URIs, like `href` and `src`, to tell them to run the script instead of accessing a URL.

Comment: Hmm, no nothing seems to change.

Comment: Is it calling the function at all? What happens when you set a breakpoint in the function, or add `alert("Sending AJAX")`?

Comment: I may need a bit more help because i'm not quite sure how to set a breakpoint.

Comment: Ok, so yeah it does look like it's calling the function

Comment: Next, check the Network tab to see if the AJAX request is being sent, and whether a response is coming back.

Comment: Under 'status' it has '404 not found'.

Comment: So your URL is wrong. I suspect you need to replace `:question_id` with the actual question ID.

Comment: You'll probably need to pass the question ID as an argument, then use `url: 'questions/' + question_id + '/links/new'`